# categories the posts month wise in wordpress?

Tags: php, date, strtotime, wordpress

i am trying to retrieve the last 8 months posts in wordpress. i have used following code to do this

```
$args = array(
              'posts_per_page'  => -1, 
              'date_query' => array(
                array(
                'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                'after' => '5 month ago',
                )
                )
      );
$query  =   new WP_Query( $args );
```

Now i am wanted to place each month posts in separate array so that i can show them month wise in front-end.
Any idea about this ??

Comment: iterate over results andat each step put the result in the corresponding array

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
    $dateArray = array();
    $dateArray[] = $date;
    for($i=1; $i<8 ; $i++){
        $month = '- ' . $i . 'month';
        $old_date = strtotime ( $month , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
        $old_date = date('Y-m-d', $old_date);
        $dateArray[] = $old_date;
    }
    foreach($dateArray as $item){
        $month_loop = date("m", strtotime($item));
        $year_loop = date("Y", strtotime($item));
        $query = new WP_Query('year=' . $year_loop . '&monthnum=' . $month_loop );
       // Do action
    }
```

I think it help to you